# Android Notification using pusher for chat

Tags: android, notifications, pusher

Using pusher, we are able to chat across different platforms, including android. In android, we want to send the notification to the user when a message is received, even when the app is not running or we are not on chat fragment. I have gone through how services and broadcastreceiver works, but it seems they are not the right solution for it. We need to implement something in a way that whenever an event is triggered in pusher, we should be able to send notification in the notification bar in the app. How can we do it?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

It's possible. Just use Global "Thread" in the place of "runOnUiThread". Here is my code of service class. If still face any problem then feel free to ask your problem.

```
Thread readthread;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Pusher pusher = new Pusher("faa685e4bb3003eb825c");

    pusher.connect();

    Channel channel = pusher.subscribe("messages");

    channel.bind("new_message", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(String channelName, String eventName, final String data) {
            readthread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("Successss","Pusher run on Background");
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Message message = gson.fromJson(data, Message.class);
                    // Notification(message);
                    // Write your code here. 
                }

            });

            readthread.start();
        }

    });
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could be a good solution => https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/

Comment: Yeah, I went through that and implemented it. We use pusher for our chat, but for sending notifications, we use cloud messaging.

Comment: You can use pusher to bind to specific event with data messages in them that act as notifictions

Answer (score 0):

Pusher doesn't presently offer support for native Push Notifications. However, Pusher does provide a way of determining if a user is currently online. Using this mechanism it's possible to determine how a message should be sent to a user.

1. If they are online send the message via Pusher
2. If they are offline send the message via email, SMS or a native Push Notification

Online user detection can be achieved in a number of ways:

1. Use [Presence channels](https://pusher.com/docs/presence_channels) and set up [WebHooks](https://pusher.com/docs/webhooks) so your server knows when a user subscribe/unsubscribes from that channel.
2. Have a unique channel for each user. If the channel is occupied then it means they are online. If the channel is vacant they are not online. You can also use WebHooks to be instantly informed when a channel becomes occupied (a user comes online) or vacated (a user goes offline).

In both cases it's also possible to use the Pusher HTTP API and [query channel state](https://pusher.com/docs/server_api_guide/interact_rest_api#querying-application-state) to determine if a channel is occupied (a user is online) and the members that are subscribed to a presence channel.

There is also a blog post on [Enabling Smart Notifications](https://blog.pusher.com/smart-notifications-with-pusher-and-sendgrid/) that demonstrates the channel querying. When the user is online the message is sent via Pusher. When they are offline they are sent an email via SendGrid.